# Disable multiple search in django restframework search_filter

Tags: python, django, search, django-rest-framework

Is there anyway to disable multiple search in Django-rest-framework using SearchFilter?

By default django-rf will apply multiple search if whitespace and/or comma appear on search string.

> xyz.com/?search=x,y

This search will return results contain either x or y (seperated by comma).

I would like to make it return results contain "x,y" as parts of string.

Comment: For full word match filter, there is a [drf -fullwordmatchfilter](https://github.com/trollknurr/django-rest-framework-word-search-filter/tree/master/rest_framework_word_filter) avaiable.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to think of a good argument and use case for this but since you want to implement such search, you must need it. 
I would subclass the existing `SearchFilter` and override the `filter_queryset` method:

```
 def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
    search_fields = getattr(view, 'search_fields', None)
    search_terms = self.get_search_terms(request)

    if not search_fields or not search_terms:
        return queryset

    orm_lookups = [
        self.construct_search(six.text_type(search_field))
        for search_field in search_fields
    ]

    base = queryset
    conditions = []
    for search_term in search_terms:
        queries = [
            models.Q(**{orm_lookup: search_term})
            for orm_lookup in orm_lookups
        ]
        conditions.append(reduce(operator.or_, queries))
    queryset = queryset.filter(reduce(operator.and_, conditions))

    if self.must_call_distinct(queryset, search_fields):
        # Filtering against a many-to-many field requires us to
        # call queryset.distinct() in order to avoid duplicate items
        # in the resulting queryset.
        # We try to avoid this if possible, for performance reasons.
        queryset = distinct(queryset, base)
    return queryset
```

This is how the method looks. A little glance at it would show you this line:
`conditions.append(reduce(operator.or_, queries))`.

You can change it to this:
`conditions.append(reduce(operator.and_, queries))`.

This should probably return your expected result